# Google login email not obtaining while using django allauth.All other datas even profile picture is getting

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am not able to obtain email address while using django allauth.In settings.py i have included the following scopes

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {
        'google': {
            'SCOPE': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
                      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'],
            'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}
        }
    }
```

I am getting all other user details except email

Comment: Well have fun debugging it! If you get stuck, ask a question on here complete with what you have tried/researched and a [mcve] that demonstates the issue

Comment: Ok sorry for my incomplete question.Now can u help why i dont get email

Answer (score 1):

`SCOPE` should be `['profile', 'email']`, not the urls

http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers.html#django-configuration

Comment: Even after using this scope email is not obtained in API  .I also enabled  SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL =True SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {'google':
         {'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
          'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}}}